# How to connect apache ignite node by static ip address

Tags: java, tcp, ip-address, ignite

I have got a hetzner server with config:

```
<bean id="ignite-configuration" class="org.apache.ignite.IgniteSpringBean">
    <property name="configuration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
            <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
            <property name="igniteInstanceName" value="statistic-server"/>

            <property name="discoverySpi">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                    <property name="ipFinder">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                            <property name="addresses">
                                <list>
                                    <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I want to connect my Laptop to server like a server node. On my laptop I have next config:

```
<property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <value>hetzner_ip_address:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="addressResolver">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BasicAddressResolver">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <map>
                            <entry key="192.168.1.10" value="laptop_static_ip_address"/>
                        </map>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Can I connect servers behind NAT by static ip address and how can I do this?

Comment: If the server is behind NAT, the only way to connect would be to set up port forwarding on the NAT box and use the NAT device's external IP address.  This is unlikely to be allowed.  The alternative is a VPN or SSH tunnel.  Explaining those is off-topic for StackOverflow as they are network configuration issues, not programming related.

Comment: Jim, could you give me a link where I can read about it?

Comment: NAT, VPN and SSH Tunnel are all very well documented on the web. Use your favorite search engine.

Comment: Jim, sorry, but if you know, I must setup ssh tunnel on server node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear weather you have a client or server node behind NAT, but actually in Ignite a server node can sometimes establish connection with a client node, so you need to make sure that connections are allowed in both directions.

In case of NAT this means that in addition to `AddressResolver` you need to configure port forwarding on the router, or use SSH tunnel.

Comment: Thank you so much. I created VPN server on my hetzner server and connect my client node to vpn.